# Calculate Angular Change in Circular Motion

Tags: algorithm, plc

I am trying to derive an algorithm that will allow me to calculate the angular displacement in circular motion. This is a physical device that I am programming so I do have feedback of the current angular position from 0 - 2pi.I have attached a photo that will help you see what I am trying to achieve (see below). Each time the processor scans through the program updates the tags and then calculates the delta theta by taking Theta2-Theta1 and then stores it into the DeltaTheta tag. The problem is that when I complete a revolution, Theta 2 becomes 0 and Theta 1 is still something like 3pi/2 or so and thus I get a larger Delta Theta than I should. Each time the angle hits the 2 pi mark, it resets to zero. I am using this program to implement an algorithm with Fourier Analysis on a Rockwell CompactLogix PLC. For those of you concerned enough I am programming in RSLogix5000 using the "Structured Text" language. Please see this site for a manual on the language if need be. [Structured Text](http://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/pm/1756-pm007_-en-p.pdf)
 See sample code below.

```
ThetaOld = Theta;
Theta = SpindleActPosition; //This is feedback from the motor 0-2*pi
DeltaTheta = Theta2 - Theta1; //This is the "algorithm" I need help with
```

I also tried this algorithm but found loop-holes in it that did not allow it to work.

```
DeltaTheta = [(Theta2 - Theta1) + 2*pi] MOD(2*pi)
```

I believe the MOD operator will be our friend in this but I am unable to find a solution to the problem.

The rest of the code really is irrelevant to solving this problem. Unfortunately by nature of this machine, the angle starts at the 12 o'clock position and then rotates clock-wise. I can't change this.

[image: Generic System Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add:

```
IF DeltaTheta < 0 THEN
    DeltaTheta = DeltaTheta + 2*pi;
END_IF;
```

Comment: Keep the DeltaTheta = Theta2-Theta1 and then implement this conditional?

Comment: Yes.  Just add this to your original 3 lines.